# How to generate a list containing the values of a table

Tags: macros, etoolbox, csvsimple

I have a table containing two columns with `x` and `y` values respectively and I want to generate a list `\coordinates` containing `(x,y)` for each row of the column.

I tried defining a command that creates a list by using the `\appto` command:

```tex
\newcommand{\coordinates}{}
\newcommand{\coordinate}[1]{%
    \ifdefempty{\coordinates}
        {\appto\coordinates{#1}}
        {\appto\coordinates{, #1}}
}
```

When calling `\coordinate{(1,2)}` and `\coordinate{(2,3)}`, `\coordinates` contains `(1,2), (2,3)`. So far this works fine.

Now I want to combine this to the `csvsimple` `\csvloop` command, to call the `\coordinate` command for each row of the table and thus generate my desired list. Unfortunately, the output of the list is `(,), (,), (,), (,)` instead of `(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)`, so TeX does not seem to enter the number to the command. What's the issue here?

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\newcommand{\coordinates}{}
\newcommand{\coordinate}[1]{%
    \ifdefempty{\coordinates}
        {\appto\coordinates{#1}}
        {\appto\coordinates{, #1}}
}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    x,y
    1,2
    2,3
    3,4
    4,5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvloop{%
    file = {data.csv},%
    column names = {x=\x, y=\y},%
    command = \coordinate{(\x,\y)}%
}

% \coordinate{(1,2)}
% \coordinate{(2,3)}
% \coordinate{(3,4)}
% \coordinate{(4,5)}

\coordinates

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe use `\eappto` or `\xappto` instead of `\appto`? I am not familiar with `csvsimple` but it might be some expansion issue.

Comment: Both work well. Thank you!